# Create active cell in Jtable Java get value at?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
private void tabelKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 

    int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        int baris = tabel.getSelectedRow();
        try {
            if (tabel.getValueAt(baris, 0) != null) {
                System.out.println(tabel.getValueAt(baris, 0));
            } else {
                cellEditor.stopCellEditing();
                Robot robot=new Robot();
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                 

                System.out.println(tabel.getModel().getValueAt(baris, 0));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Salah");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem is get value at the cell active in jtable?

Comment: I will get velue at in cell after clicked enter?

Comment: What is it you are trying achieve (as there may be a better way)? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will go a long way to clearing up the issue at hand

Comment: @AliMuthohari  how can you click Enter :).

Comment: @Shahid clik enter after wirite in one of cell table...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get value of selected cell.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class TableWithComboBox extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private boolean DEBUG = true;
    JPanel jPanel2;
    JFrame frame;
    JTable table;
    JComboBox comboBox;

    public TableWithComboBox() {
        super(new GridLayout(2, 0));

        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Add the scroll pane to this panel.

        String[] options = { "Students", "Doctor" };

        comboBox = new JComboBox(options);
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboBox.addActionListener(this);

        table.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    int col = table.getSelectedColumns()[0];
                    System.out.println(table.getValueAt(row, col));
                }
            }
        });
        add(comboBox);
        add(scrollPane);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String optionName = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        if (optionName.equals("Doctor")) {
            table.setModel(new MyTableDoctorModel());
        } else {
            table.setModel(new MyTableModel());
        }
    }

    class MyTableDoctorModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Department", "Hospital", "Experience" };

        Object[][] data = { { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },
                { "Saira", "Dep1", "XYZ", new Integer(3) },

        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
         * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
         * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
         * change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
                        + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            double totalVal = 100.0 + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(table
                    .getValueAt(0, 4)));
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        }

    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Degree", "Board/University",
                "Year of Passing", "CGPA", "Part-Time" };

        Object[][] data = {
                { "Saira", "B.Tech", "VTU", new Integer(2015), new Float(8.33),
                        new Boolean(false) },
                { "Smaira", "B.Sc", "CBSE", new Integer(2007), new Float(7.77),
                        new Boolean(true) },
                { "John", "M.tech", "IIT", new Integer(2009), new Float(8.77),
                        new Boolean(false) },
                { "Jia", "M.Sc", "Thapar", new Integer(2011), new Float(7.21),
                        new Boolean(true) },
                { "Kerry", "B.Com", "DU", new Integer(2014), new Float(8.92),
                        new Boolean(false) }

        };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
         * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
         * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
         * change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
                        + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            double totalVal = 100.0 + Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(table
                    .getValueAt(0, 4)));

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private void createAndShowGUI(TableWithComboBox newContentPane) {
        // Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jPanel2 = new JPanel();

        frame.add(jPanel2);

        // Create and set up the content pane.

        frame.add(newContentPane);
        // newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        // frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TableWithComboBox newContentPane = new TableWithComboBox();
                newContentPane.createAndShowGUI(newContentPane);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I Tried this code but this print is "null
null
null"
null

Comment: I posted the complete code. Check it now. It has few extra that is not directly related to your question but you can see how your problem is addressed in this code.

Answer (score 0):

private void tabelKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

```
    int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        int baris = tabel.getSelectedRow();
        try {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                int row = tabel.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println(tabel.getValueAt(row, 0));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Salah");
        }
    }
}
```